# Delphi question: is there way to check that Delphi object variable (Assigned(...)=True) has no content/instance?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, access-violation

I have this Delphi code:

```
  var F: TMyForm;
begin
  F:=TMyForm.Create;
  F.DoSomeActionAndFreeForm;
  if Assigned(F) then begin
    F.DoSomethingOther;
  end;
end;
```

and `TMyForm.DoSomeActionAndFreeForm` has code `Self.Close`;

The problem is, that `F` can contain no instance after `TMyForm.DoSomeActionAndFreeForm` but `F` is not `nil`, because there is not way, how object can destroy itself and notify all referencing variables about that so that they become nil.

I know, that my code is bad and somehow in-verted, but I need such code for some kind of 'unit-testing GUI' application. I wanted to write rapidly some tests, so that program can execute itself and write some journal about performance of its actions. That is why I am having such strange case.

But nonetheless, it would be nice to get to work this code.

I am afraid that there may be no way to do such basic thing. Although one crude way would be:

```
//Replace if with try...except silent catch of exception
//if Assigned(F) then begin
//  F.DoSomethingOther;
//end;
try
  F.DoSomethingOther;
except
  do E: EAccessViolation do begin
    //Do nothing - no re-throw, no message about error
  end
end;
```

Although this is not nice solution, it is though pretty "transactional" - if there is instance, then method is executed fully.

Comment: You do know that there is no guarantee you get an AV? Other possibilities include, but are not limited to: (1) everything working just as if there were a valid object; (2) your app will crash at a seemingly random place an hour later; (3) your app will incorrectly send a 2118252977 USD invoice (instead of the intended 399 USD invoice) the next day.

Comment: Anyhow, one nice pattern which would actually solve your problem right now is this: Let your `TMyForm` base class have a *class* variable `FInstances: TList<TMyForm>` which you create in the `class constructor` and free and nil in the `class destructor`. Then, in the instance `constructor`, you add `Self` to the list; in the instance `destructor`, you remove `Self` from the list. Then you can easily check, at any time, if a given pointer is found in the list.

Comment: But all those 3 effects are solely due to the fact, that memory, to which F is pointing, can accidentally contain some executable object/function that is different from the initial object instance. If instances had field with unique GUID value, then the program would be able to access and compare (if available) GUID values before the execution and that could solve such accidental mismatch.

Comment: I scarcely remember that COM objects had such reference counting.

Comment: This isn't the solution to your problem, whatever your problem actually is

Comment: Probably something like this https://dalijap.blogspot.com/2022/11/zeroing-weak-object-references.html

Comment: Just the call to `Close` doesn't necessarily free the instance. As long as no one calls `Free` on the form (or something stupid like `Application.ProcessMessages`), the form is only closed, but the instance stays valid.

Comment: It also depends if an ``OnClose`` event is present and if it's ``Action`` parameter is set to ``caFrew`` or not.